# Array with numeric keys into single array line (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any way to change or convert this type of array:

[image: Array with numeric keys]

Into something like this?:

```
[1.05, 1.24, 1.3, 1.36, 1.54....]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: Please include your example data as text, not as an image.

Comment: the array in the picture is the array you want already... it is shown 0: 1.05 in console but it is actually [1.05,,,,,]

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` to see the truth of @CharlieNg's statement.

Comment: Hi, at first you should read the tour to learn more about stackoverflow and how to ask good questions... What have you tried? Your question is not clear, also... Do you want to build a string? Then you could use a for-loop

Comment: Well I don't think this is even a coding problem, I think you used `console.dir()` if you use `console.log()` it will give you the wanted result.

Comment: Just because you are visualizing the same thing in two different ways, does not mean the underlying thing is different. I'd say both those arrays are the same.

Comment: Flagged: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_name.toStrinng(); Here is an example:

```
<code>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var array =["1","2","3","4","5"];
array.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
}
</script>
</code>
```